# "Large" xlsx file reading using C++ Qt and Qt Xlsx Module

Tags: c++, excel, qt, xlsx

I'm developing an app in C++ using Qt framework but I need to read an .xslx file to import it into a sqlite database. I'm using Qt Xlsx Module but I'm finding some difficulties since my program crashes at some random point during execution. The file is about 1500 rows and 10 columns. I'm able to read between 700 and 1000 rows but then it crashes. I think it's a memory issue but I'm unable to use Valgrind since I'm on Mac OS X system.
The relevant part of my code is below.

```
void Controller::ImportDatabase(const QString &filepath)
{
    QStringList* person_fields = new QStringList;

    QXlsx::Document *xlsx_database = new QXlsx::Document(filepath);

    int number_of_row = xlsx_database->dimension().lastRow();
    int number_of_column = xlsx_database->dimension().lastColumn();


    for (int row = 2; row <= number_of_row; ++row) {
        ++count;
        qDebug() << "count: " << count;
        for(int column = 0; column < number_of_column ; ++column) {
            if ((QXlsx::Cell *cell = xlsx_database->cellAt(row, column))) {
                person_fields->append(cell->value().toString());
                delete cell;
            }
        }
        qDebug() << "NOME: " << person_fields->at(0);

        //Create a new Person and pass its pointer around: all commented anyway

        person_fields->clear();
        delete cell;
    }
    delete person_fields;
    delete xlsx_database;
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the most basic and direct approach? Get a debug build of Qt and the XLSX module, and then run it in the debugger and see where it crashes.

Comment: 1. I don't see the need to construct person_fields and xlsx_database on the heap, stack should be sufficient. 2. Do you really need to delete the cell pointer from cellAt? There is another "delete cell" within the loop, don't see how this compiles ... 3. person_fields->at(0); might cause problems if nothing was added to the QStringList 4. As Kuba Ober said: debugging!

Answer (score 1):

Your must **NOT** delete `cell` at all, because it is owned by the QXlsx::Document.

Comment: I noticed that things get better if I don't delete it. The issue is still there though.